# Delphi Android, making first letters uppercase problem. But not on VCL

Tags: android, delphi, uppercase, letters

I tried to look at some steps about making the word automatically become uppercase letters in the first letter. I used to use it on VCL and it works very well, but why on mobile applications it doesn't work properly. I use this code, but in edit2, the result is that I lost the first letter and the words start with the second letter that I entered in edit1, even though it starts with uppercase. Maybe someone can help me. Thank you very much

```
    var i, j : integer;
        s, edt2 : string;
Procedure
         j := length(edt1.Text);
            s := '';
            for i := 2 to j do
            begin
              s := s + LowerCase(edt2.Text[i]);
            end;
            edt2 := UpperCase(edtProduk.Text[1]) + s;
```

Comment: Very inefficient to create new strings character by character. Modify the text in place. Also, do expect that your code will fail with international text.

Answer (score 3):

In Delphi mobile platforms you have to understand that strings are zero-based (just like arrays).

To avoid issues, if you want to access the first index and last index of a string in a cross platform safe way, use the `System.Low` and `System.High` intrinsics on the string.

Comment: You are very right. Thank you for enlightening me. Now I have succeeded. The basis that was forgotten by me.

Comment: "*To avoid issues, ...*" - or use `{$ZEROBASEDSTRINGS OFF}`, or use `TStringHelper`